# Algorithm to find most likely continuation of image over border from set of possible next images

Tags: image-processing, matching

Is there an algorithm that would fit in the following situation:

I have a sub image A of a larger image, and a set of sub images B that could (but not necessarily) share border with A. Now the algorighm should find likelyhood of A sharing a border with a sub image in B. There may be errors or small gaps between the sub images and the edges may not be straight, but they visually share enough structure that at least a human could visually see that the sub images fit next to each other.

In other words, a visual puzzle piece matching algorithm.

Edit: Clarifying with an image. Image gas straight lines because drawing is simpler, but the edge could also be arbitrary. And the cuts between subimages may not be pixel perfect, so that there may be small gaps between tiles etc.

[image: Picture describing problem. In column A we have the image that images in column B are compared to]

Comment: Hi. Could you please show a diagram with A and B so we can visualise this "puzzle"?

Comment: Edited. Added a clarifying image. Does this help?

Comment: Low-resource algorithm: for each possible border of A and the corresponding border of B, calculate the sum of square differences of (pixel of A - corresponding pixel of B). The lowest this sum, the more likely these two images share this border.